# How could I get code coverage for individual tests in Java

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura, jacoco, emma

I have a test class which has a bunch of test cases.

I would like to measure the coverage of individual test case in the class.

Is there any way I could get a report which maps test case and the coverage.

Comment: You want to measure what, exactly? The percentage of your entire production code base which is covered by each individual test? (However, what would be the point of that?) Or is it something else?

Comment: I want to know the classes or methods covered by a single test case in the prod code base. My purpose is not to measure the the coverage.

Comment: You can always run a single test case and then examine the coverage report produced from it. But probably you would want to run a whole test suite at at time. As far as I know, none of the existing code coverage tools for Java provide this functionality out-of-the-box (the solution from Ira's answer seems to require some coding from the user, so I am not counting it). I don't really understand the need, so I can't tell whether this functionality is worth having in a tool.

Comment: @Rogério: I agree, our solution doesn't do it out of the box.  That's because our test coverage collection tool is independent of the test execution framework.  I'd like to think the changes we suggest are pretty easy to make; a good framework enumerates then executes the tests and those changes only have to made at the (presumably single) point of the enumeration.   With that change, all the tests can run and yet coverage collection is done on a per test basis, as OP requested.

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes. For JUnit, a custom `Runner` would have to be created and specified on each test class; for TestNG, an `ITestNGListener` implementation would have to be created and configured. These two cases should cover 99% of the user base (just guessing). Still, it would take some non-trivial effort. But I suspect this isn't such a "real" need; personally, I don't see a clear use for the functionality (when needed, I simply run a single test and then check the coverage report).

Comment: @Rogério: Agreed, if OP is going to run one test occasionally then an ad hoc approach will probably work.    If the user wants to run many individual tests, he could simply write a script the run them one by one.  But then he has to manually track the results of each test, if he want to retain/compare them.  The value in the customization is that it ensures that each test always collects a clearly labelled result.   And that's just repeated work.   One assumes that Runner or ITestNGListener can be modified to inherit from a base implementation that handles the individual test; should be easy.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it :) Will update in some time

Comment: @SachinFrancis
7 years later, I need the update :D 
How did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Our [SD Java Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/JavaTestCoverage.html?Home=JavaTools) tool can give you this data.

This tool adds a special class TCV with methods to the program under test:

```
    TCV.reset();  // resets the test coverage vector
    TCV.dump(); // writes vector to file
    TCV.setBaseName(String); // record vector file name prefix
```

If the application calls the dump function, a test coverage vector is dumped to a file named with the current timestamp and the supplied BaseName.

You can use these to obtain test-specific vectors by modifying your test execution framework, whatever it is, just slightly.  Where ever you invoke the Nth test case, add a call to dump:

```
    TCV.reset(); // marks everything as "not executed"
    tests.nthTestCase();
    TCV.setBaseName("nthTestCase");
    TCV.dump();
```

This will produce a time stamped vector that covers just the code executed by the nTestCase.

Individual test case results can be found and displayed by the UI component of the tool.  The UI component can also combine all those individual test case coverage results, into an overall test coverage result, to give a traditional "everything executed by all test cases" result.  Or, you can compare test case coverage results to see which test cases cover the same code, to help eliminate redundant test cases, etc.

The UI component can also produce a report of lines covered by a test; this can be scripted, so one could produce a line-covered report for all test coverage vectors collected individually.

Comment: Thanks, But I am not on Windows

Comment: Hmm.   Well, you could run the tool's instrumenter part on Wine (this is well tested); you can do this with shell scripts provided by the product.  The rest of the tool is Java-based and will run native on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Clover [Clover](https://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/overview/test-optimization)

I know it's not free but it should give you what you need.